# How to efficiently generate a special co-author network in python pandas?

Tags: python, networking, pandas, graph

I'm trying to generate a network graph of individual authors given a table of articles. The table I start with is of articles with a single column for the "lead author" and a single column for "co-author". Since each article can have up to 5 authors, article rows may repeat as such:

```
| paper_ID | project_name | lead_id | co_lead_id | published |
|----------+--------------+---------+------------+-----------|
|     1234 | "fubar"      |     999 |        555 | yes       |
|     1234 | "fubar"      |     999 |        234 | yes       |
|     1234 | "fubar"      |     999 |        115 | yes       |
|     2513 | "fubar2"     |     765 |        369 | no        |
|     2513 | "fubar2"     |     765 |        372 | no        |
|     5198 | "fubar3"     |     369 |        325 | yes       |
```

My end goal is to have a nodes table, where each row is a unique author, and an edge table, where each row contains source and target author_id columns. The edges table is trivial, as I can merely create a dataframe using the requisite columns of the article table.

For example, for the above table I would have the following node table:

```
| author_id | is_published |
|-----------+--------------|
|       999 | yes          |
|       555 | yes          |
|       234 | yes          |
|       115 | yes          |
|       765 | no           |
|       369 | yes          |
|       372 | no           |
|       325 | yes          |
```

Notice how the "is_published" shows if the author was ever a lead or co-author on at least one published paper. This is where I'm running into trouble creating a nodes table efficiently. Currently I iterate through every row in the article table and run checks on if an author exists yet in the nodes table and whether to turn on the "is_published" flag. See the following code snippet as an example:

```
articles = pd.read_excel('excel_file_with_articles_table')
nodes = pd.DataFrame(columns=('is_published'))
nodes.index.name = 'author_id'
for row in articles.itertuples():
    if not row.lead_id in nodes.index:
        author = pd.Series([False], index=["is_published"], name=row.lead_id)
        pi_nodes = pi_nodes.append(author)
    if not row.co_lead_id in nodes.index:]
        investigator = pd.Series([False], index=["is_published"], name=row.co_lead_id)
        pi_nodes = pi_nodes.append(investigator)
    if row.published == "yes":
        pi_nodes.at[row.lead_id,"is_published"]=True
        pi_nodes.at[row.co_lead_id,"is_published"]=True
```

For my data set (with tens of thousands of rows), this is somewhat slow, and I understand that loops should be avoided when possible when using pandas dataframes. I feel like the pandas `apply` function may be able to do what I need, but I'm at a loss as to how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `df` as your first `DataFrame`, you should be able to:

```
nodes = pd.concat([df.loc[:, ['lead_id', 'is_published']].rename(columns={'lead_id': 'author_id'}, df.loc[:, ['co_lead_id', 'is_published']].rename(columns={'co_lead_id': 'author_id'}]).drop_duplicates()
```

for a unique list of `author_id` and `co_author_id` with their respective `is_published` information.

To only keep `is_published=True` if there is also a `False` entry:

```
nodes = nodes.sort_values('is_published', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['author_id'])
```

`.sort_values()` will sort `True` (`==1`) before `False`, and `.drop_duplicates()` by default keeps the first occurrence [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). With this addition I guess you don't really need the first `.drop_duplicates()` anymore.

Comment: Thanks, this is really close to what I'm looking for! The only issue is if I have an author listed once with `is_publisehd = False` and once with `is_publisehd = True`. Wouldn't your one liner keep both entries?

Comment: Yes, because these would not be duplicates. Which one do you want to keep, or what's the logic for selecting between the two?

Comment: The logic is to set "is_published" to true if the given author_id has at least once plublished paper. Hence if there were duplicates, it would always choose the "is_published" = true if possible, otherwise default to "is_published = false